# There's a conceptual error in Java String method

Tags: java, string, ocpjp

Here I was training to my OCP and test some String behaviors.

And when i get this:

```
    System.out.println("a".substring(0) == "a".substring(0));  // true

    System.out.println("a".substring(0) == "aa".substring(1)); // false
```

Some doubts came to me. I know what that method returns is:

```
    return (beginIndex == 0) ? this : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
```

But, theres a conceptual error on this compiler rules or thats all ok?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Don't .  OCPJP requires some especific knowing about Java implementation.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case `substring` returns `this`, and `this == this` returns true as expected.
In the second case, `substring` returns a new object so `==` returns false because you are comparing different objects.

Comment: @user3220398 why what? Why is substring implemented that way?

Comment: @user3220398 if `beginIndex` is 0 then the result of `substring` is the original string, so instead of creating a new string, substring just returns `this`. That is more efficient CPU and memory wise. I'm not sure I understand why you think this is an issue.

Comment: About performance it's all right. About the concept, that's what i mean, if user don't know the implementation of language, this behavior  has an exception , a single case isolated. So by the way, the static context "this" not always pointing to the same memory heap, ok?

Comment: @user3220398 `substring` does not guarantee anything about returning the same or a different string instance. So the current implementation is fine and returning a new string would be fine too.

Comment: @assylias Interestingly enough, the javadocs for `subString()` say that a new String is returned... So it seems that returning `this` could be just a performance optimization since you aren't supposed to assume that you get the same string back.

Comment: I see - it is indeed a bit ambiguous. You should have phrased your question that way!

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong equality operator. You want `.equals`, not `==`. Whether or not the strings returned by the method calls you're using are the same string objects is an implementation detail; you want `.equals` to compare their contents.

Comment: To a pratical effect you are right. But in this case, i was expect that operator "==" ever returns false with substring() method, knowing that it return a String instance with "new" operator. I just don't understand why only in case of the parameter beginIndex == 0. Why return static context with "this" instead new String(this.value) for example?

Comment: @user3220398 `s.substring(0)` just returns `s`, so the runtime **could** just return the same reference as `s`.  That doesn't mean it necessarily will.  You can't count on it.  But it might.  That's one reason **never** to use `==` with `String`s even if you think you can tell when it will return a different reference.

Comment: @ajb I've been satisfied now. I know however was implemented, the method runs fine with the right use. I **might** use "a" == "a" , but I'm sure that is true because at that runtime  this==this. But i'll never use it.